# Strange redirection issues on wordpress from ssl with padlock to ssl without padlock

Tags: redirect, ssl, hosting

First time posting here so hopefully Ive got the right question in the right place.

I recently moved servers and then decided to add a ssl certificate.  Since the move traffic has plummeted.

Looking at the site it seems that when you hit a site it doing some sort of redirect.

On the iPhone this is most obvious as hitting an article on http://essentialmac.co.uk you'll see the padlock for a moment and then it looks like its redirecting and you're served a https page but with no padlock up in the url area.

This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can any please, please help.  Thanks.

Comment: in your general settings what is your site url and location of wp installation?

Comment: both WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are set to https://essentialmac.co.uk.. I have tried adding the WWW but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do they both have https:\\ at the beginning?

Comment: @MarkC Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a dated question and I see that the SSL (`https://`) is now running on the website mentioned by the OP, I feel this question still needs some closure to anyone else that has a similar issue:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://essentialmac.co.uk/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your non-SSL links in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.